# Exporting fiddler session as .jmx for JMeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, fiddler

Has there any option(s) / work around to export fiddler trace files as .jmx files to be imported into JMeter?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this:

- http://www.perftesting.co.uk/creating-jmeter-test-plans-with-fiddler/2013/03/01/

Another option is to use HAR format (chrome or firefox+firebug+plugin) and use this:

- https://blog.flood.io/convert-har-files-to-jmeter-test-plans/

Edit on 25 october 2020:

- Since version 5.3 of JMeter, you can use menu Tools > Import from cURL which will allow you to import in JMeter a session exported as a set of cURL commands

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/curl.html#hints

Answer (score 1):

Blazemeter have a [free tool](http://converter.blazemeter.com/) where you can convert exported HAR files from fiddler and save them as jmx files.

Worked very good for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an extension which can transform HTTP request to any other text format as long as you can create a simple Mustache template for it. Recently I created a template to convert Fiddler Http request to JMeter project i.e. JMX file. It's a basic template but you can customize as per your needs.

https://github.com/hemantsharma-io/MockingBird#convert-a-get-http-request-to-jmx-ie-jmeter-for-perf-testing-in-fiddler